# Codeigniter: Retrieving data from multiple tables and displaying results

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing my first big application using codeigniter and need a little help as I am fairly new to it all. I know how to get records out of the DB and display them, but I now have to get results from two tables and display them. I pass $data to the view, it works fine for $data['prop'] but I can't get the rest.

`$data['prop'] = $this->ManageProperty_model->get_property_details($p_id);

$data['img'] = $this->ManageProperty_model->get_property_images($p_id);

$this->load->model('ManageBranch_model');

$data['branch'] = $this->ManageBranch_model->get_branch_details($p_id);`

I usually echo out results like so:

    `<?php foreach ($prop as $p) : ?>

    <?php echo $p->ID; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>`

Even if there is only 1 row being returned as I am not sure of another way.do I need a foreach for img and branch?

Answer (score 2):

How about using a join?

I dont know whats in your model but if you try something like

```
        $this->db->from('property');
        $this->db->join('branch', 'branch.id = property.id');
```

You can put a where statement in there too if you need something particular.

This means you have a more complex model but less loops and arrays and messy stuff in the view which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, currently you're just getting one or the other. You're probably better to put it into a multilevel array like `$data['property']['prop']`.

Comment: How would you display this? and do I always have to have a foreach loop. In this case I know there will only be one result returned. Seems daft to have a loop in there

Comment: First off, you *never* "know" that only one result will be returned unless you put a `LIMIT 0,1` on it. Second, why are you using a foreach loop then? Shouldn't your `ManageProperty_model` take care of that and simply return the object so you can say `$prop->id, $img->image_link, etc`?